# Estimating Probabilities in R

Tags: r, model, probability

I am trying to analyze some probability data with R. The data I have gives the frequency of certain outcomes (*A* and *B*)  for a given probability *p* and what I want is a model that will allow me to estimate *p* from only the frequency data.

Right now I am just running a linear regression (something like `lm(p ~ A + B)`) which works more or less but I know that this is not the "right way" to do it. In particular, my current model will, for some values of *A* or *B*, return values that do not lie within the interval `[0, 1]`, i.e. that are not valid for a probability.

I am pretty sure there is a way to do this, but I can't for the life of me figure out what the model was called or how to run it in R. Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "frequency of certain outcomes (A and B) for a given probability p" -- can you clarify or give a sample data set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot just run `lm(p ~ A + B)` as there is no *model* relating your *count variables* A and B with the probabilities:  `lm()` fits a linear regression to model an *unbounded* real variable as a function of a linear combination of real variables (where you can substitute count variables).

The easiest model for probabilities is a [**logistic regresion**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) which uses a logistic function to make from unbounded real values to the bounded interval [0,1]. You can fit logistic regression in R using `glm()` as well as a number of add-on packages for special cases, see e.g. [this rseek.org search for logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression).

Also, [CrossValidated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) is a good site for modeling questions such as this.

Answer (score 0):

Poisson regression, implemented in R with the glm function with family="poisson" (with a default log link) ,  would estimate a log-linear model which very directly can be used to estimate probabilities. Depending in how you set up the input of the dataset you can get either proportions or rates by exp(linear.predictor). It would be somewhat similar to you current use of lm()  set up as lm(log(p)~ A+B) but the errors are more appropriate to counts. The [piece that Zeileis, el al, did for package pscl](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pscl/vignettes/countreg.pdo) is particularly good at presently the method in the context of other methods for analyzing count data (see section 3.2):